# Where are the Native API call in JDK for Abstract Window Toolkit

Tags: windows, awt, java

As Abstract Window Toolkit is abstraction over the underlying native user-interface of host operating System. But I am looking over source code of `java.awt` I didn't find any native call to underlying operating System.

If AWT uses native API's to create ui then in case of windows , JDK must call the `createWindow` function of win32 SDK to create a Window.

Can anyone help me to find where are those native API calls in JDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWT is built on a dynamic library provided with the JDK (awt.dll in windows).  That native DLL keeps its interface across all the target OSs of the JDK, but the concrete implementation of that DLL is rewritten in C or whatever language for every platform.

Answer: you will find native windows API calls in that library (awt.dll), which is something like an abstraction layer for the underlying OS